# Formatting computer without Windows license

Tags: windows-7, windows, formatting, license

I have an old computer that I use for streaming on my TV (The screen on the computer is cracked)
I want to format it, haven't done so in a while, BUT, about a year ago my harddrive crashes and the guy who fixed it upgraded Vista to Windows 7. Not long ago my windows license expired (honestly I didn't know it could), and the fixer guy will only fix the license if I bring the computer to him. (It's a long and annoying trip, so I'm not really keen on doing that).
So! My question. Is there any way to format this computer properly?

Comment: Someone might correct me on this but licenses shouldn't "expire". What I've seen happen is a license will be revoked because the software was not genuine to start with. I bet your license was used on another machine or maybe even several machines and your Windows has simply invalidated itself...

Comment: Yes;  You install your original legal license of Windows Vista.  The Windows 7 installation was likely cracked unless you were provided a Windows 7 COA assume that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

You can format it with any bootable disk/CD/DVD/USB/PXE system - The main thing is that you can't be running your OS from the drive that you want to format. You can even download a Linux distribution, and use that to format it. You'll need an operating system though, so that's why I'd recommend Linux.

The fact that your Windows had "expired" leads me to believe it either wasn't an authentic copy, or it was an evaluation of Windows 7 Enterprise.

If you still have your Vista DVD (or can download one legally), you can re-use the COA (Certificate of Authenticity) key that should be on your computer, with the 25-digit product key.